# Unsure if structure has been initialised

Tags: c

From my last post I'm dealing with my code block by block to make sure it's all working and there's something very strange going on.

If you look at my code, when it comes to initialising the structure with the unique student IDs it will happily print them after each one has been initialised inside the for loop (which suggests to me it's obviously done it) but, however, when I want to print them again outside the for loop in another for loop as a "double-check" it goes horribly wrong, presumably they're not in there at all?

If you traverse the code to the bottom you'll see my comments.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define ROWS 80
#define SIZE 100
#define STUDENTS 20

int string_compare(void const *x, void const *y)
{
    return strcmp(*(char**)x, *(char**)y);
}


struct student
{
    char student_ID[SIZE];
};



int main(void)
{
    FILE* input;
    int i,j,data_items;
    int records=0;
    char buffer_IDs[ROWS][SIZE];
    char buffer_subjects[ROWS][SIZE];
    int marks[ROWS];
    char *string_ptrs[ROWS];
    struct student db[STUDENTS];

    if((input=fopen("C:\\marks\\marks.txt", "r"))==NULL)
        perror("File open failed!");
    else
    {
        while ( ( data_items=fscanf(input, "%s %s %d", buffer_IDs[records], buffer_subjects[records], &marks[records])) == 3) {
        printf("%s %s %d\n", buffer_IDs[records], buffer_subjects[records], marks[records]);
        string_ptrs[records]=buffer_IDs[records];
        records++;
        if ( records > ROWS) {
            break;
        }
    }

    }

    qsort(string_ptrs, records, sizeof(char*), string_compare);

    for(i=0;i<records;i=i+4)
    {
        j=0;
        strcpy(db[j].student_ID,string_ptrs[i]);

        printf("%s\n",db[j].student_ID); /*Happily prints the unique IDs contained in the structure*/
        j++;
    }

    for(i=0;i<STUDENTS;i++)
        printf("%s\n",db[i].student_ID); /*Does NOT print them outside the for loop which initialises the structure. */


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How do you knows it's happily printing and not doing it begrudgingly.

Comment: Any reason why you're using `i=i+4` instead of `i++`?

Comment: How many records do you have?

Comment: @barakmanos `i` is indexing into `string_ptrs`. `j` is what indexes into `db`

Comment: @DrewMcGowen: I see that, but I still don't understand the need to "jump" 4 pointers at each interation in **the second** loop when `records` is incremented only once at each iteration in **the first** loop.

Comment: You zero `j` at the beginning of the `for` loop and then increment at the end. Logic error?

Comment: OT: This `if ( records > ROWS) ` shall be `if ( records >= ROWS)`.

Comment: What's the `j=0;` for?

Comment: I think the first thing you'd have to learn is to ask good questions :) SO is no a site for code review but for concrete technical questions. Please boil your code down to something readable and think of what you really wanting to ask.

Answer (score 8):

Looks like your first for loop is always printing only the first student id. at the beginning of the loop, you set j as 0, and at the end you increment it. But, after each step of the loop, the j becomes 0 again.

So, only the first student id are being "initialized", and the next elements are all uninitialized.

Answer (score 1):

Why is your "initialization" cycle jumps over 4 string pointers at each iteration

```
for(i=0;i<records;i=i+4)
  ...
```

?

This cycle will initialize only `records / 4` elements in the `db` array. I.e. the final value of `j` will tell you how many elements in `db` have meaningful `student_ID` values. (And which will be only `1`, since as Alef noted in his answer, you reset the value of `j` on each iteration of "initialization" cycle).

Later you print `STUDENTS` elements. `STUDENTS` and  the final value of `j` are unrelated. What if `STUDENTS` is greater than `j`? Expectedly, you will print complete garbage from uninitialized elements of `db`.

Comment: Because the student ids have been q sorted. There's 20 students, four subjects which means there's 80 in total. So I've qsorted them, and to extract the unique Ids I have to jump every four.

Comment: @Tripswitch I don't think you're using `qsort` properly; you're just sorting a list of strings, not a list of records.

Comment: @Tripswitch: Well, firstly, there's nothing in your code to suggest that "20 students, 4 subjects" relationship and there's nothing in your code to ensure that it is actually the case. That's just asking for trouble. Secondly, what I said above stands in any case: you have `records` records, which allow you to initialize only a certain number of elements of `db` array. And then you print `STUDENTS` elements of `db` array. These values are unrelated. How did you expect it to work?

Comment: If you look at my previous posts you'll see. The data in the file goes like:580313 English 91
580313 Mathematics 97
421311 Physics 74
223170 English 81
131782 English 51
421311 Computing 11
528191 Mathematics 85
886030 English 84
832912 English 94
003953 Mathematics 29
073241 English 99
131782 Mathematics 59
075160 Mathematics 9

Comment: @Tripswitch: Great. Now imagine that your input file contains only *one* student with 4 subjects. That will give you `records` equal to `4` and only one student in the `db` array in the end (after you fix the `j=0` problem). Yet, you always attempt to print `20` student IDs... Why are you printing `20` IDs when you could only have `1` or `5`?

Comment: so there are four different subjects. Now I need to get the unique IDs in my structure to populate their marks. The qsort function is to only be used on the buffer_IDs, and yes it works. In my for loop, because it skips every four, it will only loop 20 times which gets hold of the unique student ids and j will only be incremented 20 times for twenty students. Yes I know it's a fixed number, but i'll see to the probram dealking with more than this at a later point.

Comment: I've done it now, j keeps being to zero INSIDE the for loop. I've moved it outside and everything's working great, thanks guys.

Comment: I'll get back to the other questions soon.

Comment: @Tripswitch: If everything is set and known in advance, fixed at compile time (a rather bad programming practice, BTW), then why on Earth do you maintain and extensively use that `records` variable? Why does your `qsort` sort `records` records instead of explicitly sorting exactly `STUDENTS` (i.e. `20`) records? Why is your first cycle iterates to `records` instead of iterating to `STUDENTS`? Why do you have a *variable* in your code, if, as you say, the number of records is not variable at all?

Comment: I use the records variable because it counts how many rows of data there is, which could be unknown. Yes I agree, fixed numbers is bad practice, but for now I'm just focused on making sure I can get the required tasks done then I'll remove fixed numbers to fine tweak it.

Comment: @Tripswitch: Well, that's the whole point. You are saying now that the number of records could be *unknown*. But your second cycle is implemented as if the number of records is *fixed* and always *known*. Why is the first cycle implemented for *unknown* number of students and the second cycle for *fixed* number of students?